# UEFI setup has NO keyboard or mouse, how to recover

Tags: boot, uefi

UEFI setup has NO keyboard or mouse. Can not perform any setup. When I boot into previously setup windows 10 they are OK. Previously setup 16.04 is now not accessible. I suspect something like too much fiddling has caused UEFI to go into a security mode but I can not find a way to make any changes. Problems started when I tried to boot into terminal mode to install NVIDIA drivers, which can not be installed if X is active. I have tried booting iso files to re-install but lack of keyboard/mouse stops that. Is it possible to reload a UEFI setup code? Also Boot Repair disk and GParted Live are now without keys or mouse! Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You did not give any information on your hardware/BIOS, so it is difficult to help. I once had a similar problem, as the BIOS was configured (not?) to use legacy USB and thus did not recognize keyboard and mouse. I had to reset the BIOS to the initial state (look in the documentation of your MoBo), then set USB to `legacy mode on boot`, so input devices were recognized at boot without OS drivers.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED Cleared CMOS and keys/mouse came back in UEFI setup! Aparently the UEFI software in my ASROCK J3455M motherboard can "BRICK" itself by forcing ignoring even the CD/DVD. Now I have to proceed, carefully, to get a useable boot setup! P.S. found solution because with CD/DVD and all drives disconnected from SATA the problem remained so short of "self flashing" the only stored memory was CMOS.